# JS Onchange display value before processing

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a `form` with a `select` input element. After the user selects an option, I check that option chosen. If it is bigger than I expected, I bring up an `alert` box asking the user if they're sure they selected the right option. This is just a warning, so I don't reset the value or prevent the user from selecting these options.

Currently, this causes the `alert` to display first, and then the option on the webpage is changed AFTER they hit `OK`.

How can I get the value in a `select` element to display the selection before I process it during the `onchange` event?

```js
mySelectElement.onchange = function() {
    if(mySelectElement.value >= 1000) {
        alert("Are you sure you can eat that many apples?");
    }
    // else nothing, less than 1000
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple solutions, one don't use an alert. You can use a modal library, or just output to the dom.

If you must use an alert,wrap it in a setTimeout so its delayed.

```js
let select = document.querySelector("select");

select.addEventListener("change",function(){
  if(select.value > 1){
    setTimeout(function(){alert("Alert");},100);
  } 
});
```

```html
<select ><option value="0">A</option><option value="3">3</option></select>
```

Comment: @Barmar, I'm understanding the problem as when the user makes a selection in the select, they can't see the selected option until AFTER they click the OK button on the alert. So this will show the user the selected option, then wait a brief period then pop up the alert.